# Clojure range with a specific start and infinite end

Tags: clojure

According to the [docs](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/range) the `range` function has four forms:

- `(range)` 0 - Infinity
- `(range end)` 0 - end
- `(range start end)` start - end
- `(range start end step)` start - end skipping by step

So how would I declare a range representing `x` to Infinity?

I may also be asking how do reference infinity, as something like `(range x infinity)` might work?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`(iterate inc x)` will give you a lazy, infinite sequence of numbers starting with `x`.

Comment: And works for large n much quicker than the other common suggestion of `(drop n (range))`

Answer (score 8):

How about something like this:

```
(defn my-range
  ([start] (iterate inc' start))
  ([start step] (iterate #(+' % step) start)))
```

Please note `inc'` and `+'` to support arbitrary precision.

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
(defn range-from [start]
   (drop start (range)))
```

Comment: I like the intuition behind this answer better than the `iterate` answers, but I wonder whether it would waste computation if `start` is a large number.

Comment: @Mars agreed - I think this answer hopes that whatever efficiency is lost is dwarfed by the rest of the infinite range - ha!

And it does preserve whatever optimised representation `range` uses...

Comment: If you want to preserve range then using solution originally proposed by @Sean could be a better idea: `(defn range-from [start] (map #(+' start  %) (range)))`

Comment: @zero323 I get the intuition: shift the whole sequence to the right by adding a constant. In terms of the advantages of this answer, not so keen in that your suggestion requires an extra add over the infinite part of the range. In terms of generalising these answers away from integers, it becomes a trade-off between evaluating and dropping the `start` terms of the sequence and then getting free access, versus applying an offsetting function on every reference, but getting the first return quicker. For sequences of integers, obviously, performance is almost certainly a red herring.

Comment: I get your point, but  unlike `drop` approach, map preserves behavior of the `range` function. If I call `(first (filter some-pred (range-from 1)))` and `(first (filter some-pred (range-from some-very-large-number)))` running time is affected only be an estimated distance to the first value that meets criteria. Taking it to the absurd lets say I call it like this `(first (filter #(zero? (rem % 2)) (range-from (Math/pow 10N 128))))`. I will argue that to get a result in a predictable time vs never is an ultimate performance gain :)